# How to create a PHP object defined in a WSDL document using NuSOAP

Tags: php, nusoap

I'm trying to consume a web-service (written in .NET, FWIW).

A method I'm trying to call takes a `WSCredentials` object as a parameter.  Said object is defined in the WSDL as follows:

```
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://services.example.com/foo/bar">
[...]
<wsdl:types>
  <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://services.example.com/foo/bar">
[...]
    <s:complexType name="WSCredentials">
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Username" type="s:string"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Client" type="s:string"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Password" type="s:string"/>
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
[...]
```

I have tried faking it with an array:

```
$CREDENTIALS = array(
    'Username' => $WSCREDENTIALS_USERNAME,
    'Client'   => $WSCREDENTIALS_CLIENT,
    'Password' => $WSCREDENTIALS_PASSWORD,
);
```

... and also without the keys:

```
$CREDENTIALS = array(
    $WSCREDENTIALS_USERNAME,
    $WSCREDENTIALS_CLIENT,
    $WSCREDENTIALS_PASSWORD,
);
```

Neither of these work.  When I call the method that takes this as a parameter with code like this:

```
$result = $client->call('SomeMethod', array($otherParameter, $CREDENTIALS));
```

... I just get a response status 400:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 30 Oct 2015 11:07:08 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Is there some special way to instantiate a `WSCredentials` object?

Comment: Agresso web service, by any chance?

Comment: Yes, its Agresso.  FWIW, I was able to get this working the the native PHP SOAP client.

Comment: Thought I recognised it! I'm doing much the same in Python. Glad you got it working.